# How can I disable Internet access for programs running in Wine?

Tags: linux, fedora, wine

How can I disable Internet access for programs running in Wine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run wine as a seperate user, you can use the iptables owner module to disable internet access.
For instance, if you create an user "wine", you can use the following commands:

*iptables -A OUTPUT --uid-owner wine -m tcp -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset* #fast, but only for tcp

*iptables -A OUTPUT --uid-owner wine -j REJECT #all other protocols*

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/). For example:

```
firejail --noprofile --net=none wine iexplore
```

Look for error messages in the terminal to see that internet is not working.

```
0009:fixme:urlmon:InternetBindInfo_GetBindString not supported string type 20
0009:fixme:ieframe:handle_navigation_error Navigate to error page
```

Answer (score 2):

Wine uses an equivalent of the Windows registry, accessed through regedit as with a normal Windows system. I would imagine there is a key buried in there somewhere that you could use to disable the network connection, or at least make it local-only. (I'm not an expert on the Windows registry, so I can't say where unfortunately)

Alternatively, You could try setting Wine to use a proxy to access the internet, which would obviously fail if the proxy you specify doesn't exist. That is a bit of a hack though.